# Adding a comment model to associate with a post/user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I finally was able to associate a user model with a post model with:

```
def create
 @post = Post.new(post_params)
 @post.user = current_user
```

Right now I'm trying to create a comment in the `Post#Show` page but continue to receive an error regarding my form. The two errors I'm running into are:

```
NoMethodError in Posts#show undefined method `comments_path'
```

when I have `@comment = Comment.new` in `Post#show`. When it's removed I get:

```
ArgumentError in Posts#show First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

What could possibly be wrong with my form? Also if someone can recommend a better way to associate my 3 models (basically have a `user_id` and a `post_id` when comment is created I'm open for suggestions). My comment form is going to appear within the `Post#Show` page. My current code is:

*Comment Model*

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

*User Model*

```
has_many :posts
has_many :comments
```

*Post Model*

```
has_many :comments
belongs_to :user
```

*Comment Controller*

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :find_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def index
  @comments = Comment.all
 end

 def new
  @comment = Comment.new
 end

 def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
  @comment.user = current_user

  if @comment.save
   flash[:notice] = "Successfully created..."
   redirect_to comments_path
  else
   flash[:alert] = "failed"
   redirect_to root_path
  end
 end

 def show
 end

 def edit
 end

 def update
  if @comment.update
   flash[:notice] = "You updated your comment"
  else
   flash[:alert] = "Failed to update"
 end

 def destroy
  @comment.destroy
  redirect_to '/'
 end

 private

  def find_comment
   @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def comment_params
   params.require(:comment).permit(:comment)
  end
end
```

*Post Controller*

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user = current_user
    if @post.save!
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created..."
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "failed to add a post"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @post.update
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated"
      redirect_to post_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Failed to update Post"
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if @post.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully delete"
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Wasn't able to delete Blog post."
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  private
    def find_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :description)
    end
end
```

*Post#Show View*

```
<%= render '/comments/form' %>
```

*Comment#form*

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :comment, "Title" %>
  <%= f.text_field :comment, placeholder: "Write a comment" %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

If there is something missing please ask me to update my post. Thank you all who help me better understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your associations seem fine. The error

```
NoMethodError in Posts#show undefined method `comments_path'
```

means that you don't have the route `comments_path` or `Comments#Create`. Basically, when you have a `form_for` with a `Comment` as the parameter, it assumes you are wanting to go to the `create` or `update` route, depending if it's a new record. The easiest thing to do would be to add

```
resources :comments
```

to your routes file. However, since you want a comment associated with a post, you want to modify your routes file to have:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

Then, change your form to look like this:

```
<%= form_for [@post, @comment] do |f| %>
```

So when you submit a form, you will have a `params[:post_id]` and a `params[:id]` to play with. Find the `Post` with the `params[:post_id]`. Ignore the `params[:id]` when you're creating a comment, but use it when you're updating a comment.

Edit: [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) is a link to some help regarding Nested Resourcing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Somehow I did miss adding resources :comments. Got a question regarding nested associations. If I do that it'll be posts/:id/comments when listing all the comments. Is this better when trying to make them show in Post show instead?

Comment: I'm also running into an error now after making the changes. It's saying for my comment create controller with Couldn't find Post with 'id'=. After creating a comment I notice it's taking me to posts/:id/comments. Is it because of my redirect_to in controller? Thank you for the help.

Comment: You can do it both ways. Nested resources is a more structured way of doing things, especially for beginners.

You would need to find the `Post` with `params[:post_id]` and `Comment` with `params[:id]` (if the comment was already created).

Comment: Your redirect in the current code should just take you to `/comments`. If you change it to `comments_post_path`, then it should take you to `posts/:id/comments`.

Comment: You my friend are godly! Thank you so much for your help. I still need to practice more to get a better feel/understanding for forms/models and controller association but it works beautifully now :)

Comment: just one final question. If I want to list all the comments listed in a specific post. Would it be <%= @comment.post %> ? what if I want to list as well the user information associated with that post? like their username for example.

Comment: If you have a `@post`, then `@post.comments` would give you all the `comment` objects associated with that. You would want to use `.each` to iterate through them to display each of them. `@post.user` would give you the `user` object associated with it. Of course, always check to see if that association isn't `nil`!

Comment: Currently playing/trying out what you recommended and with <% @post.user.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.user.email %>
  <%= comment.comment %>
<% end %>
I was able to have user email showing with the comment they posted.

Comment: Thank you for your help Ryan. Learned a lot of new things and also appreciate the link regarding nesting. Currently reading up on it :) have a great day.